# Web scraping: help needed last post and find link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

First, sorry for my poor English.
Actually, I have a script which **scrapes** a website to find comments in webpage, in python.
Its for **scrape** all messages in page, but I will want **scrape** just last post.
How to do this please?
Too, I will want to find web links probably posted in last message, but a full link.
Its possible?
Here is the webpage link and script:

https://www.dealabs.com/discussions/suivi-erreurs-de-prix-1063390?page=9999

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-47-66784467-1-0-1-0-aide-scraping-python-forum-dealabs.htm
# scraping_dealabs.py

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 

url = "https://www.dealabs.com/discussions/suivi-erreurs-de-prix-1063390?page=9999"

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

# Accepter les cookies
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]/span"))
)
button.click()

# On recherche les commentaires et on affiche le texte
comments = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("commentList-item")

for comment in comments:
    _id = comment.get_attribute("id")
    author = comment.find_element_by_class_name('userInfo-username').text
    content = comment.find_element_by_class_name('userHtml-content').text
    timestamp = comment.find_element_by_class_name('text--color-greyShade').text
    comment_url = f"{url}#{_id}"

    print("Posté par", author)
    print(content)
    print("Publication:", timestamp)
    print("Lien du commentaire:")
    print(comment_url)
    print('-' * 30)

driver.close()
```

Thanks for time ans reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'd like you to use correct locators, so instead of `/html/body/main/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/button[2]/span` try using this CSS selector `.btn--mode-primary.overflow--wrap-on`.
In order to get the last comment you can use this XPath: `(//div[@class='commentList-item'])[last()]`
So in order to get the last comment details only your code can be modified to be like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-47-66784467-1-0-1-0-aide-scraping-python-forum-dealabs.htm
# scraping_dealabs.py

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "https://www.dealabs.com/discussions/suivi-erreurs-de-prix-1063390?page=9999"

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

actions = ActionChains(driver)

# Accepter les cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn--mode-primary.overflow--wrap-on"))).click()

last_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='commentList-item'])[last()]")

actions.move_to_element(last_comment).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
last_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='commentList-item'])[last()]")

_id = last_comment.get_attribute("id")
author = last_comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'userInfo-username')]").text
content = last_comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'userHtml-content')]").text
timestamp = last_comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'text--color-greyShade')]").text
comment_url = f"{url}#{_id}"

print("Posté par", author)
print(content)
print("Publication:", timestamp)
print("Lien du commentaire:")
print(comment_url)
print('-' * 30)

driver.close()
```

**UPD**
To get the last element on the page, as you described in the comments, you have to change the locator from

```
last_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='commentList-item'])[last()]")
```

to

```
last_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='commentList-comment'])[last()]")
```

So that entire code above will be:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/42-47-66784467-1-0-1-0-aide-scraping-python-forum-dealabs.htm
# scraping_dealabs.py

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

url = "https://www.dealabs.com/discussions/suivi-erreurs-de-prix-1063390?page=9999"

options = Options()
options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

actions = ActionChains(driver)

# Accepter les cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn--mode-primary.overflow--wrap-on"))).click()

last_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='commentList-comment'])[last()]")

actions.move_to_element(last_comment).perform()
time.sleep(0.5)
last_comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='commentList-comment'])[last()]")

_id = last_comment.get_attribute("id")
author = last_comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//span[contains(@class,'userInfo-username')]").text
content = last_comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'userHtml-content')]").text
timestamp = last_comment.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(@class,'text--color-greyShade')]").text
comment_url = f"{url}#{_id}"

print("Posté par", author)
print(content)
print("Publication:", timestamp)
print("Lien du commentaire:")
print(comment_url)
print('-' * 30)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Prophet
But when i start your script, i get an error:

```
, line 36
    author = last_comment.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@class,'userInfo-username')]').text
                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```
You know why i have this err please?

Comment: ups, I'm sorry. I have fixed that. I hope now it will work correctly

Comment: Thx. It work now, but the script out now only first post, not last. Its strange

Comment: Try giving some delay, like `time.sleep(3)` after `EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn--mode-primary.overflow--wrap-on"))).click()`. To let the comments loaded. Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Ok. i tested this, but always first comment is out.

Comment: wait. What do you mean by the last comment? The upper comment?

Comment: Lower comment on the comments list

Comment: I see there are 5 comments there, below them paging buttons and below them some other comments, not matching the `commentList-item` class name

Comment: I want to say last comment on the commentList item. Is possible to do the script do execute with only last comment on the comment list please?

Comment: Not top comments, only last lower comment on commentList element

Comment: Actually, it has 5 top comments (Not want), and 31 comments below matching in commentList-item. I just want last comment on these comments, when i start the script

Comment: Again, last is the one who appears on the top of those 31 comments or on the bottom of the page?

Comment: Sorry for understanding. Last message is on the bottom of the page

Comment: I have just last request please. If the member post a link, it will be scrap on text only, not full link. Same as here:

```
amazon.fr/dp/…DD/
```
The link is really for example:
```
https://www.amazon.fr/gp/product/B07QV64LV7
```
The link is here on the source code:
https://ibb.co/0BT2PBd

Is possible to help me, for scrap a possible link (is possible post not have a link) in last post please?